# Fullscreen app to continue working in the background

Tags: java, android, html, background, fullscreen

I have made an Android app for a smartwatch in order to show fullscreen an HTML5 webpage existing of alternating a real-time clock and an event with a progress bar how long this event still will run (the html5 page can be seen on www.janvangalen.nl.
However the smartwatch falls back to sleep mode (which is intentional), but I cannot get the app continue to operate in the background. Vibrate (to notify of new activities) does not work and activating the watch shows the clock still running, but the activity is still the one that was there at the moment of going to sleep.

I have developed in Android Studio and the following files are the base of my app.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nl.janvangalen.www.imagewatch">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

**acitvity.fullscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_fullscreen_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And finally:

```
**FullscreenActivity.java**

package nl.janvangalen.www.imagewatch;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint; 
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //Remove notification bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_fullscreen_webview);

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.janvangalen.nl");

}

}
```

I have also found the way how to get apps working in the background and made an new .java (fort the second public class). However, in the following code, I do not know exactly WHAT to input, making it work.

```
package nl.janvangalen.www.smartwatch;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import nl.janvangalen.www.imagewatch.R;

public class RSSPullService extends IntentService {
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    // Gets data from the incoming Intent
    String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();
    // ...
    // Do work here, based on the contents of dataString

}
}
```

What WORK needs to be done there as the work is already done in the fullscreen script.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. By using foreground in stead of background!